# store certificate which we got via SSL handshake

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-client-authentication

We have done client certificate authentication via `SSLVerifyClient require` method. Now authentication is being done as required.

Now we want to store the `client certificate` which we is being presented by the client during SSL handshake.

Is there a way I can save the client certificate which I am getting during authentication into a directory or somewhere? I need to get the public key and CN information from the client certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache provides the full certificates and extracted parts of it using a variety of environment variables, like SSL_CLIENT_CERT  for the full certificate or SSL_CLIENT_S_DN  for the subject DN. See [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) for more details on this.